# Assets not showing up for second site

Tags: assets, multi-site-manager

I'm setting up Multi-Site for ExpressionEngine and when I go to manage my files in the P&T Assets plugin, nothing shows up. The refresh icon just spins. Even when I create a new upload destination within the folder of the second site, I get nothing. Updating the index just makes the button transparent like something is happening, but nothing does.

Comment: How are your file upload preferences setup? Are you using a multi-environment config.php?

Comment: It's the same environment for both sites so I'm using the regular config. Uploading works fine from the default uploader. It's just Assets that has issues.

Comment: I'd try sending an email to support@pixelandtonic.com then. I wouldn't mind seeing your config.php file setup either.

Comment: They sent me to a link under [http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/using/config.html](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/using/config.html) You have to set $assets_site_url in index.php

Comment: Just as I thought :)